# Setting windows policy for service users

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-services

I wan't to set up windows policy definitions (specifically, block access to removable media) to service users.

For a regular user, I use the following definition in the registry:

```
[HKEY_USERS\<uid>\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices]
"Deny_All"=dword:00000001
```

but service users don't have a registry hive - so there's no where to perform this definition.

Is there a method to apply a policy (or other user specific registry setting) to a service user?

Answer (score 1):

If by "service user," you mean the system accounts (Local System, etc.), their user profile is stored in `<windows directory>\System32\config\systemprofile`. You can start RegEdit and mount the NTUser.dat file that is stored in that folder. That will give you access to their HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: I mean both these users, but also user defined users which are used to run services

Comment: For any user, you're going to need to have their NTUser.dat open. Either log in as that user (if it's a "normal" user account) and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies...  or mount their NTUser.dat as described.